# How can I write unit test for kendo DropdownList using Jest and React testing library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {DropDownList, MultiSelect} from "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns"
import '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css'

const Filter = () => {
    
const [QS,setQS] = useState({id:0,name:"All"})
const options=[{id:0,name:"All"},{id:1,name:"red"},{id:2,name:"green"}]

    return (
        <div className="filter">
                <DropDownList  title="QSDropdown" data={options} defaultValue={id:0,name"All"} value={QS} dataItemKey="id" textField="name"
                onChange={(event)=>{
                    setQS(event.target.value)
                }}/> 
        </div>
    )  
}

export default Filter
```

How can I write unit test for this kendo DropdownList in Jest and React testing Library.

I am writing the following unit test:

```
import {render, cleanup,fireEvent,getAllByRole} from "@testing-library/react"
import Filter from '../Components/Filter'

const options=[{id:0,name:"All"},{id:1,name:"red"},{id:2,name:"green"}]

it('can change the value of the dropdown', () => {
    
    const { getByTitle}=render(<Filter />)
    const dropdown = getByTitle("QSDropdown");
    fireEvent.click(dropdown);
    const dropdownOptions = getAllByRole(dropdown,"option",{ hidden: true });    
    fireEvent.click(dropdownOptions[1]);
    expect(dropdownOptions[1].selected).toBeTruthy()
    expect(dropdown.value).toBe(options[1].name)
});
```

Getting error: Unable to fire a "click" event - please provide a DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

By default DropdownList options are appended to `body`, not the dropdown element itself. As a consequence `getAllByRole(dropdown,"option",{ hidden: true });` fail, because it's using the dropdown element as container.

If you have a single DropdownList you can use screen and omit the container: `screen.getAllByRole("option",{ hidden: true })`

Otherwise you can pass `popupSettings` to your DropdownList component and specify a container or a class that you can then use to retrieve the options in your test. Example:

```
<DropDownList
    data={sizes}
    popupSettings={{ className: 'myOptionContainer' }}
/>
```

See the available settings [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dropdowns/api/DropDownsPopupSettings/).

Also, you probably need to wait for the options to be rendered after clicking on the dropdown control (for that use `findBy`, instead of `getBy`):

```
it('can change the value of the dropdown', async () => {
    ...    
    fireEvent.click(dropdown);
    const dropdownOptions = await screen.findAllByRole("option",{ hidden: true });
    ...
});
```

Comment: But now I am getting following error:                               expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "BVT"
    Received: undefined                                                                                                   Why am I getting dropdown.value = undefined  ?

Comment: Did you try waiting for the value? `await waitFor(() => expect(received).toBe(expected))`

Comment: Yes, I am using await waitFor, still getting dropdown.value undefined.                                           Is this the right way to access the value selected for the dropdown?

Comment: I'm not a Kendo UI user, but it seems the selected value gets stored in a hidden `<select>` that is a child of the `dropdown` element in your test. So you should be able to retrive the select element using `dropdown.getByRole('combobox', { hidden: true })` or similar

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it works the same in React as it does in Vue, the dropdown list DOM is not added near the dropdown itself, but it's added as a child of the `<body>` element.

There is a link between these elements though. The dropdown will have an `aria-controls` attribute (or `aria-owns` in older versions) that contains the id of the list of dropdown elements. You can use `document.getElementById(...)` to find the dropdown element you want:

```js
const dropdown = getByTitle("QSDropdown");
await fireEvent.click(dropdown);

const dropdownOptionsRoot = document.getElementById(dropdown.getAttribute("aria-controls"));
const dropdownOptions = getAllByRole(dropdownOptionsRoot, "option", { hidden: true });    
await fireEvent.click(dropdownOptions[1]);
```